# enable_shared_from_this not working on xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang, llvm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class Test: public std::enable_shared_from_this< Test<T> >
{

public:

    std::shared_ptr< Test<T> > getMe()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    };

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test<int>   aTest;

    return 0;
}
```

When i try to compile this on Xcode 5 i get

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'shared_from_this'
```

I tested it and its working on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You forgot to qualify it with `std::` like so `std::shared_from_this()`.

Comment: No here std namespace only required for extending from enable_shared_from_this and in return type of getMe function and they are already typed.

Comment: Plus shared_from_this is member function on enable_shared_from_this class. Are you sure you are reading the question?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
    return this->shared_from_this();
           ^^^^^^
```

VC++ 2010 does not implement the lookup rules for templated base classes exactly correctly.  The clang behavior is correct.  The above fix will make it work on both your platforms.

Comment: +1, so that it is easier to google for more related information this is a problem with lookup for *dependent* and *non-dependent* names. Without the qualification `shared_from_this` is **not** a dependent name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats did the trick. I still don't understand why it needs 'this' here. Any doc to check for this?

Comment: @ali_nakipoglu: Well, there is always the standard... in particular 14.6.2/3 *In the definition of a class or class template, if a base class depends on a template-parameter, the base class scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.* But you can also google for two phase lookup.

Comment: Also http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#dependent_base and the links given there.